# PHP : Captcha verification code not working properly;

Tags: php, captcha

I am creating a very simple Captcha verification process.

(When a user tries to log into my website 3 times, without success, he is re-directed to the Captcha Page  (captcha.php), to verify that he is not a spam-bot)

The Captcha value itself is randomly generated from a string of letters and numbers.   6 digits in all.

And then, I compare this value with the value entered by the user into a text-box.  if the values match, the user may proceed. If not, the page reloads, an error message is displayed, and a new captcha is generated.

Very simple. No javascript, no ajax.

Except for one thing :  the Captcha is NOT re-directing if the user provides the correct value.

Instead, it gives the error message every time.

```
  <?php session_start();

   include 'database_connect.php';

   function getRandomString($length)  {
   $validCharacters =  
   "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";
    $validCharNumber = strlen($validCharacters);
    $result = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $index = mt_rand(0, $validCharNumber - 1);
    $result .= $validCharacters[$index];
    }
    return $result; }

    $captcha_value = getRandomString(6);

    ?>

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-store">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0">
        <META CHARSET="UTF-8">      
        <title>Captcha Test</title>         
  </head>
 <body>
    <fieldset><legend>CAPTCHA :</legend>

     <?php 
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                $post_captcha = $_POST['captcha'];

                if ($post_captcha == $captcha_value) {

                $clear_failed_logins =  mysqli_query($conn,("Delete FROM 
                                        login_attempts where login = 
                                        '$_POST[login]'")) 
                                        or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 

                header ("Location: /example.com/login.php");    
                exit();     
            }
            else {

            echo "<p style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'>The value you  
                   entered is not correct! Please try again.</p>";
             }
          }
        ?> 

        <p>Please input the characters you see into the text-box below :</p>
        <p>  <?= $captcha_value ?> </p>
        <form method="POST" action="captcha.php">
        <input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" size=10 
                     autocomplete="off" required><br><br><br> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT"> 
        </form>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: yes, because after submitting the form it generates again a new value for `$captcha_value`

Comment: because when the page loads for the first time submit is not set. thats why it displays error message. You have to change the condition and introduce some more error checking varibales.

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect with header in php after you output something to the user, so move that if else block to the top of you page before something get output.
If you want to redirect at this position try a meta refresh

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.domain.com">
```

Additionally you should store the captcha value in the form because it get regenerated every time the page get refreshed (so after a form submit), i suggest you to try it with [reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html), that is easy to implement and alot more secure

Comment: Thanks for the response, Rocky.  I did have the IF-ELSE block at the top of the page, but it was not working (the $captcha_value was not being generated, since it comes only after the if-else).  That's why I moved it to its current position.   I need the $captcha_value in the IF-ELSE block.  How can I position it properly?

Comment: You can do this with a hidden input <input type="hidden" value="captcha value" name="captchavalue"> that is also bad because the user or bot's can see this in the source code

Comment: I meant : how to re-position the IF-ELSE block

Comment: you need the correct captcha value, so you can store that in a session/cookie or like i said above in the form that you can check it against each other so $_POST["captcha"] === $_POST["captchavalue"] or with session you do if you generate the captcha $_SESSION["captcha"] = $captcha_value; and then if you check if its correct $_SESSION["captcha"] === $_POST["captcha"]

Comment: Thanks, but I did that already, as I mentioned earlier.  Using SESSION or COOKIE won't change anything, if the IF-ELSE condition is in the wrong place

Comment: do that right in the start as you need only the session/post variable